# How do I effectively use multiple Storyboards for 100+ view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

So I have an app that will contain 100+ view controllers in Storyboard when it's done. I would like to create multiple storyboard for better organization and less lag while in development. I will have a main.storyboard that contains the 6 main categories (view controllers) and will branch off into the other view controllers (whether in the same or another storyboard).

I would rather not create a reference to each of my 100+ view controllers outside of the main.storyboard. I use the navigator to move around my view controllers as such:

```
let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'll provide any other information/clarification or additional code on request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a bit more background on the nature of the application?  It's unusual to require so many view controllers.  Are you sure you can't make any of them more generic so that they can be re-used?

Comment: As @Jim mentioned, it looks unusual to have that many view controllers. If you do need them, I'd suggest organizing them into multiple storyboards (based on your categories). When instantiating the view controller, you only need an extra line to specify the storyboard.
  

`let someXYZViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "CategoryXYZ", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someXYZViewController") as! SomeXYZViewController`
  
Also, have a look at `storyboard references`. https://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards

Comment: Its an instructional app. Each page is different than the next. The font, images, all the spacing etc. I realize there might be other ways of doing it. But this strangely seems the least time consuming and more direct method.

Comment: Are you creating a new view controller for each screen of content?  That's not a great way of building a content-heavy application.  You should come up with a data representation of the content, then have a view controller for each type of content.

Comment: @Jim, I have thought of that before, and I will most likely look into doing that in the future (such as the next ver. of the app). Currently I still lack experience, being fairly new at app development. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @KiranDwarkan. I think you helped me solve my issue. Rearranging my categories between multiple storyboards (instead of keeping them in a main storyboard) should do the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break up your view controllers by *functional areas*, creating a dedicated storyboard for each (or even more than one). You can then link them together using *[storyboard references](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards)* if, for instance, you are worried you might lose the big picture view.

You can even do this storyboard refactoring afterwards by using the handy *Extract Storyboard*  Xcode menu option (i.e., select a VCs subset and then click menu Editor > Extract Storyboard).

Of course, assuming you really need that many view controllers to begin with ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will keep these things in mind.

Comment: I ended up breaking the storyboards into main.storyboard (which contains the 6 main categories and some tools), and then the tools1.storyboard, tools2.storyboard, etc. I did create references to each of the tools from the main.storyboard, and a reference to the 6 categories from the other storyboards.